# Introduction to Filters in Topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, filters, online-resources

**Question:** What are some good resources for a student who has taken algebraic and point-set topology and who wishes to learn how filters and ultrafilters are applied in topology?

**Motivation:** I've seen in a number of papers where ultrafilters are briefly mentioned as tools which can be used to generalize an argument or something, but the few papers I've found which introduce filters mainly use them as as tools in Logic and mention topology only in passing. The Wikipedia page gives some good starting points, but I felt that it was more of a reference list than an introduction to the topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bourbaki's *General Topology, Volume 1* devotes a chapter to filters. The notion of net and equivalence between filters and nets is developed (partly in a set of guided exercises) in Kelley's *General Topology*. *The use of ultraproducts in Commutative algebra* by Schoutens might interest you. *The theory of ultrafilters* by Comfort and Negrepontis is encyclopedic. Jech's *Set theory* has a chapter on ultrafilters. Sections 4 and 6 of Chang and Keisler's *Model Theory* is also worth a look. These are all available on the website library.nu.

Answer (score 12):

Filters and ultrafilters play a basic role in topology: they allow for a general theory of convergence in topological spaces when sequences do not suffice.  Moreover, they do so in an arguably somewhat more graceful and canonical way than the rival theory of nets: see [my notes on convergence](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/convergence.pdf) where I develop nets, then filters, then compare the two.  But either way the theory of convergence in topological spaces is a sort of "finished product" -- it is there for you to use, and it is certainly useful, but the theory itself and how to apply it seem to be by now rather thoroughly understood: for instance, the theory of convergence stands at almost exactly the same point today as it did after the publication of Bourbaki's *Topologie Générale* by 1950.  (Or so is my impression.  Please let me know if I am simply speaking from ignorance.)

On the other hand, the use of (especially ultra-)filters in mathematics generally is definitely on the rise, especially in recent years.  The fundamental construction here is the [ultraproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) of structures.  Its importance in model theory is guaranteed by the [theorem of Jerzy Łoś](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los%27_theorem).  Very roughly, the ultraproduct of a family of structures inherits all the elementary properties shared by "most" of the structures in the family while at the same time being very conveniently "large" (in more model-theoretic terminology, ultraproducts enjoy good *saturation properties*).  This leads swiftly to the idea of *nonstandard models*, which were initially most popular in analytic contexts.  But nonstandard methods seem not to have really caught on with the majority of the analysis community.  It is not so in algebra, algebraic geometry and number theory, where "nonstandard methods" are becoming increasingly, um, standard.  My guess is that 10-20 years from now, ultrafilters will be a very familiar topic to graduate students, because of their model-theoretic applications.

To get just a little taste of the use of ultrafilters in model theory, you could read [the final chapter](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/modeltheory2010Chapter6.pdf) of the lecture notes for the short summer course on model theory I taught in 2010.  (If you don't know any model theory already, you'll need to look at the earlier chapters as well to really understand it, but perhaps you can gain an impression of what's going on just by skimming this chapter.)  But that's barely the tip of the iceberg: there are whole books written on this subject, e.g. by (Bell and Slomson) and (Chang and Keisler).

Finally, the study of saturation properties of ultraproducts leads quickly to some nontrivial set-theoretic considerations.  The fact that model theorists know and care much more about set theory than many other working mathematicians can probably be traced to this, at least in part.

Comment: I found when reading your (excellent, btw) notes on convergence was that nets indeed feel as a very natural generalisation of sequences, but *subnets* do not feel at all like a generalisation of subsequences. It's very natural to think of passing to a subsequence as "picking out" a subset of elements in the sequence, but a subnet can have a larger cardinality of the indexing set...?! In contrast I find the notion of finer (pre)filters to be much nicer - it's all just set inclusions.

Comment: @kahen: Well, then you really did read my notes, because that's exactly the perspective I present there: subnets are strange, and it seems that they exist only as the necessary tool to prove the basic theorems on convergence.  Finer filters are very natural.  Anyway, I'm glad you liked the notes...

Comment: link is dead, new link https://web.archive.org/web/20091211052932/https://math.uga.edu/~pete/convergence.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As far as online resources:

- [Notes on convergence](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/convergence.pdf) by Pete Clark,
- [Blog post](https://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/07/18/ultrafilter-convergence-compactness-and-the-spectrum-of-a-boolean-algebra/) by Todd Trimble,
- [Blog posts](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/ultrafilters/) by Terence Tao (see also the posts tagged ultralimit-analysis and nonstandard-analysis)

I am also writing a [series of blog posts](https://qchu.wordpress.com/tag/ultrafilters/) (unfinished) on the subject.

Comment: There's also David McIver's *[Filters in Analysis and Topology](http://www.efnet-math.org/~david/mathematics/filters.pdf)*

Comment: kahen's link is broken, you can still check the web archive though [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20071009170540/http://www.efnet-math.org/~david/mathematics/filters.pd)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Uniform Spaces and Semimetric Spaces. Filters play a very important role in these theories since a uniformity for a set $A$ is a filter on $A \times A$. I recommend the book Topology for Analysis by Albert Wilansky. In my opinion he's one of the best mathematics authors.

Answer (score -2):

Also consider [my book](http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html). It is not a standard course on general topology, but rather a generalization of general topology.

In my theory all general topology is based on filters (and filters are studied in my book in details, making it definitely the world best reference on the topic of filters).

In fact, it is not general topology, but its generalization. However, limit, connectedness, continuity, limit (even generalized [limit of discontinuous function](http://www.mathematics21.org/limit-of-discontinuous-function.html)), etc. appear in my theory just like as they appear in standard general topology. And these concepts are expressed by nice algebraic formulas, not as a mess of quantifiers as in any other topology book.

Curious fact: Continuity generalizes for multivalued functions in three different ways.

My theory applies both to calculus and to discrete mathematics.

You can study my theory after or before legacy general topology. The book even contains an introduction for beginning students who know only basic calculus and basic set theory.

Comment: It seems that the links no longer work - here is a link to a Wayback Machine snapshot [from October 2019](https://web.archive.org/web/20191016174110/http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html).